# Adding multiple lines of means for two separate groups using ggplot / stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

newbie here.

I'm attempting to create a jitter plot of gene expression 2^-dCt values (p2ndCt in the data frame), for two different genes, along with two separate lines representing the means. My samples are an ordered series of cell lines. I have the data in a data.frame as follows:

```
       Sample  gene   dCt       p2ndCt
1  K562 naive e14a2 -1.34 2.531513e+00
2   DMSO ctrl e14a2 -0.40 1.319508e+00
3      0.5 nM e14a2 -1.93 3.810552e+00
4        1 nM e14a2 -3.06 8.339726e+00
5        2 nM e14a2 -4.17 1.800094e+01
6      3.5 nM e14a2 -4.70 2.599208e+01
7        5 nM e14a2 -3.58 1.195879e+01
```

...

```
67       5 nM  e6a2 -2.06 4.169863e+00
68      10 nM  e6a2 -0.02 1.013959e+00
69      15 nM  e6a2  7.52 5.448217e-03
70      25 nM  e6a2  0.75 5.946036e-01
```

I am wanting to have stat_summary() separate the e14a2 means from the e6a2 means within each sample, however I'm not sure how to do this in the existing data.frame. I've tried this code:

```
##BCR-ABL1 dCt qPCR graph
BCRABL1_dCt <- read.csv('~/Manjaro/workspace/BCR-ABL1_dCt.csv')
BCRABL1_dCt$Sample <- factor(BCRABL1_dCt$Sample, levels = c('K562 naive', 'DMSO ctrl', '0.5 nM', '1 nM', '2 nM', '3.5 nM', '5 nM', '10 nM', '15 nM', '25 nM', '50 nM', '200 nM'))

BCRABL1_dCt_plot <- ggplot(BCRABL1_dCt, aes(x = Sample, y = p2ndCt, color = gene)) + geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0) + stat_summary(aes(y = p2ndCt, group = 1), fun = mean, geom = 'line', size = 1, color = 'red')
e14a2_dCt_plot
```

...which just gives me one line averaging both the genes. I've read that I could possibly put the genes in different data.frames, but would preferably do it all in one. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Maybe `group=gene` instead of `group=1` in `stat_summary`?

Comment: I have tried group = 'gene' and group = gene, they both result in the same graph as group = 1 unfortunately

Comment: After reading about the group argument, I see why group = gene should work there. I'm unsure whether stat_summary calls from the data.frame directly, or through ggplot()

Comment: Hm. Weird. I just added my suggestion as an answer. Maybe this helps to figure out or clarify what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code with snippet of data provided gives one line of means by `Sample`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(BCRABL1_dCt, aes(x = Sample, y = p2ndCt, color = gene)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = p2ndCt, group = 1), fun = mean, geom = 'line', size = 1, color = 'red')
```

[image]

However, using `group=gene` instead of `group=1` gives me a line of means for each `gene`:

```r
ggplot(BCRABL1_dCt, aes(x = Sample, y = p2ndCt, color = gene)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = p2ndCt, group = gene), fun = mean, geom = 'line', size = 1, color = 'red')
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
BCRABL1_dCt <- read.table(text = "       Sample  gene   dCt       p2ndCt
1  K562_naive e14a2 -1.34 2.531513e+00
2   DMSO_ctrl e14a2 -0.40 1.319508e+00
3      0.5_nM e14a2 -1.93 3.810552e+00
4        1_nM e14a2 -3.06 8.339726e+00
5        2_nM e14a2 -4.17 1.800094e+01
6      3.5_nM e14a2 -4.70 2.599208e+01
7        5_nM e14a2 -3.58 1.195879e+01
67       5_nM  e6a2 -2.06 4.169863e+00
68      10_nM  e6a2 -0.02 1.013959e+00
69      15_nM  e6a2  7.52 5.448217e-03
70      25_nM  e6a2  0.75 5.946036e-01", header = TRUE)

BCRABL1_dCt$Sample <- gsub("_", " ", BCRABL1_dCt$Sample)
BCRABL1_dCt$Sample <- factor(BCRABL1_dCt$Sample, levels = c('K562 naive', 'DMSO ctrl', '0.5 nM', '1 nM', '2 nM', '3.5 nM', '5 nM', '10 nM', '15 nM', '25 nM', '50 nM', '200 nM'))
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, I have tried again and it has worked properly, thanks so much for this!